# VB Select case not working

Tags: vb.net

I started writing program which takes text and encodes It into image.
I started implementing checking each character and then It writes the color onto the bitmap.

The program works fine, but when i implement `Select case` then the program stops working at select case, but throws no exception.
**The thing is that `MsgBox("done")` never gets executed.**

```
        Dim bitmap As New Bitmap("C:\abcimage\templ.jpg")
        Dim input = InputBox("What do you want to encode into image?")
        Dim characters As Array
        characters = input.ToCharArray
        Dim Width As Int32 = bitmap.Width
        Dim Height As Int32 = bitmap.Height
        Dim textcord As Integer = 0
        For y As Int32 = 0 To Height - 1
            For x As Int32 = 0 To Width - 1
                If textcord > Len(characters) Then
                    bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black)
                Else
                    Select Case characters(textcord)
                        Case "a" Or "A"
                            bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128, 128))
                    End Select
                End If
                textcord += 1
            Next
        Next
        MsgBox("Done")
        bitmap.Save("C:\abcimage\outputs\asdf.jpg")
```

Edit: I even tried `If`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't think the `Len()` function supports arrays: `If textcord > Len(characters) Then`. Why are you even using ancient VB6 methods when you can use native .NET methods? You can skip the whole `characters` array and just check the string's length directly: `If textcord > input.Length Then`.

Comment: I tried, but the problem isn't here. It works normally without `If` or `Select Case`.

Comment: Then you have to debug your code. Step though the code using breakpoints and inspect variables along the way. It is the only thing that can tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I don't know where or in what context this code runs, but check the `Immediate Window` to see if any silently thrown exceptions are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for overclocking your brains today, but the problem was with the indexation of string, I forgot it starts with 0.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
Case "a" Or "A"
```

should be this:

```
Case "a", "A"
```

If you'd read the documentation for `Select Case` then you would have seen that.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix my problem, It still stops executing.

Comment: If that doesn't fix your problem then your problem wasn't the `Select Case` statement. Maybe you should do some proper debugging, narrow down exactly where the behaviour of the code differs from your expectation and then provide us with all the relevant information on that. I'd also suggest that you turn `Option Strict On` because that can lead to some hard to detect issues. You're using a `Char` value in your `Select Case` so the `Case` should actually be using `Char` values, i.e. `Case "a"c, "A"c`.

Comment: I don't know, when i remove the `Case` and add in `MsgBox(characters(textcord))` it works. But when i use `Case` or `If` it just stops...